# Time complexity in case of multiple "in" operator usage in a condition in python

Tags: python

Suppose I have 3 elements that I want to check if they are in an iterable say (`str` or `list`).

I'm going to use an `str` as an example now but it should be the same in the case of a list:

Assuming values to check for are `'a','b','c'` and string to search in is `'abcd'` saved in variable `line`.

There are "two" general ways of doing this:

One is to just do multiple checks

```
if 'a' in line and 'b' in line and 'c' in line:
    #Do something
    pass
```

Another is to use `all`

```
if all( sub_str in line for sub_str in ['a','b','c']):
    #Do something
    pass
```

I want to know if there is any time-complexity difference between the two approaches.

Comment: Why don't you test it and determine that on your own?  By the way, trying to define time complexity for such a small sample is probably not going to give you any reasonable results.  remember time complexity is a measure of performance based on size of data being processed.

Comment: Probably worth noting that if you are doing a lot of membership lookups and are worried about performance you should be using a hashed data structure like a dict or set, rather than an iterable.

Comment: @JaredSmith Yes, I would normally use a set, I was just wondering about this in general. It's not related to any "real" code or anything,

Comment: @itprorh66 You are absolutely correct I should have tested it on my own! but as you said it won't make sense for such little data and I'm not aware of the implementations/optimizations that python does for these things (if any). That's why I asked this in case someone else knew about it.

Comment: The asymptotic complexity  is the same; its's a trade-off between constant-factor speedups and readability.

Comment: It's meaningless to talk about the growth of hand-coding millions of literal variables, unless you talk about the time to generate the code. Remember time complexity is relevant only where the size of the input can increase.

Answer (score 6):

Hard to say about time complexity, but the first is actually faster at runtime, presumably because it doesn't involve

- a name lookup (`all`)
- a function call (`all`)
- a generator expression
- <del>a list construction (`['a','b','c']`) (though this may be negligible for an imported module)</del>
  See comments.

See for yourself:

```
# All found
~ $ python3 -m timeit -s "line = 'fooabc'" "'a' in line and 'b' in line and 'c' in line"
20000000 loops, best of 5: 55 nsec per loop
~ $ python3 -m timeit -s "line = 'fooabc'" "all( sub_str in line for sub_str in ['a','b','c'])"
5000000 loops, best of 5: 397 nsec per loop
# None found
~ $ python3 -m timeit -s "line = 'fooddd'" "'a' in line and 'b' in line and 'c' in line"
50000000 loops, best of 5: 25.2 nsec per loop
~ $ python3 -m timeit -s "line = 'fooddd'" "all( sub_str in line for sub_str in ['a','b','c'])"
5000000 loops, best of 5: 325 nsec per loop
```

Comment: The condition `_ in ['a', 'b', 'c']` is compiled to use a tuple (which is loaded as a constant), so there is no cost for creating a list.

Comment: Does the compiler actually make it a constant tuple..?

Comment: Yes - `dis.dis` says it's `LOAD_CONST   2 (('a', 'b', 'c'))`.

Comment: Thanks, that does make sense!
Also, did not know about the timeit usage like this, will be very handy.

Comment: That's neat! I guess it's a special case.

Comment: There is a similar special case for `in` of a literal set - it'll be compiled to a frozenset.

Comment: Just keep in mind that it's an implementation-dependent optimization, not a feature of Python itself.

Comment: Also, this uses the example where all elements are actually ***in*** the iterable. What happens when none of them are and then `all`'s short-circuiting might be faster than checking all elements?

Comment: `all` short-circuits in exactly the same way the series of `and` operators does.

Comment: @chepner /*facepalm*/ good point...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yeah, added a comparison of that too for completeness.

Comment: For `n` containment tests, both are O(n). The `all` simply has more per-test overhead for the reasons stated in the answer.

Comment: @kaya3 Out of curiosity, I dug in: [here's the commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/b7fbcd396fc4a366433cf6f26cae64fecb056099) adding the set optimization to CPython 2.7 :)

Answer (score 1):

Both are O(*mn*) where *m* is the number of values to search and *n* is the length of the string.

There is no simple way to do asymptotically better. If you wanted to test for `or` instead of `and`, you could write a regex like `a|b|c` and it would take O(*n*) time to scan a string of length *n*, so long as you use a regular expression library which guarantees linear time searches (which is possible by using finite automata, but the standard library's `re` module doesn't give this guarantee).

But you want to test whether *all* of the patterns match, which is harder to do with a regex. If the patterns cannot overlap, then a regular expression can still work; you will need to iterate through the matches and keep track of which patterns have been found so far (e.g. using a set). Again, this will take O(*n*) time if you use a regex library that guarantees linear time searches.

If the patterns can overlap, then it's still not theoretically impossible to do with a regex (because an intersection of regular languages is regular), but it's impractical. An alternative approach would be something like the [Aho–Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) which can find all matches of a set of strings in O(*n*) time, including overlapping matches. This algorithm is not available in the standard library but there appear to be [several third-party packages](https://pypi.org/search/?q=aho%20corasick) which implement it.

All of that said, if *m* is small then I expect it is hard to get any significant improvement in actual running time compared to the simple O(*mn*) approach, even if other algorithms theoretically have a lower complexity.

Comment: @chepner Regular expressions are compiled into something like a DFA which only needs to consider each character of input once, at least for regexes which don't use features like backreferences or lookarounds which would require backtracking. Not magic.

Comment: @chepner But there is no need to check the input characters one-by-one with a chain of `if`/`else` statements; you just build a lookup table which maps each pair of (DFA state, character) to the next DFA state, and you can look up the state transition from that table in O(1) time per character regardless of how large the table is. It doesn't seem like the standard library's `regex` module uses DFAs but there are other third-party regex libraries on PyPI which do use DFAs and therefore will achieve linear time for searching regardless of the number of patterns (with some initial cost).

Comment: @chepner The DFA works as I described: you build a lookup table mapping each pair of (state, character) to the next state, and then you have a loop like `for character in string: state = lookup_table[(state, character)]` with an extra check to see if the current `state` is accepting. As you know, lookup in an array or a hashtable is O(1) time regardless of the size of the data structure. Incidentally, this is similar to how KMP or Boyer-Moore are able to search in linear time independently of the length of the pattern, since they use a state transition table to avoid backtracking.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I wasn't reading carefully enough.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if there is any time-complexity difference between the two approaches.

**TL;DR: no.**

The `all()` approach has overhead inherent in calling a function, and producing a generator for the argument to `all()` also has a cost.  But I expect these costs each to scale as O(1) with any problem dimension you choose, and you perform each one exactly once, so they have no impact on asymptotic complexity.

I expect execution of an `all()` to contribute a linear scale factor with respect to the number or elements available from the iterable presented to it.  In the first program, however, changing the number of elements to test would require modifying the program, so this number is not an adjustable parameter.  Therefore, scaling with respect to it is irrelevant for the purposes of the comparison we're considering.

Supposing that the "Do something" is the same in both cases, there remains only the evaluations of expressions of the form `x in line`.  The two alternatives evaluate the same number of such expressions, with the same operands, so these scale the same in the two alternatives.